# Can time spent with others be counted as ma'aser, according to halacha?

Tags: tzedakah-charity, maaser-tithes

I have a question about tzedakah. In regards to the giving of 10 percent of one's income, it is my understanding that one can count the giving of resources and time spent helping others as part of the required 10 percent of income. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

Harav Melamed gives this exact answer on the website Yeshiva.org.il:

> שאלה : האם אפשר במקום לתת מעשר לבצע עבודות חשמל עבור ישיבה שאני
>   מעוניין לתרום לה? וכיצד להחשיב את עלות העבודה שלי, לפי התעריף הקבוע או
>   לפי תעריף מוזל? תשובה : אם זו עבודה שאותו מוסד היה צריך לשלם עבורה
>   כסף, הרי שעבודתך שווה כסף, ואפשר להחשיב את עבודתך כתשלום במקום המעשר.
>   ויש לחשב את עלות העבודה לפי התעריף המוזל, שכך מקובל בין אנשים שיש
>   ביניהם קשר טוב, שמבצעים זה לזה עבודות בתעריף מוזל. ועוד שיש לחוש שמא
>   היצר יטה את החשבון כלפי מעלה, כדי להיפטר מתשלום מעשר, וכדי להיות
>   בטוחים שהחשבון הוגן, יש ללכת לצד השני, על פי תעריף מוזל. עוד צריך
>   לציין, שכיוון שזו עבודה שהיה יכול לקבל עליה כסף, ממילא יש להחשיב כמעשר
>   רק תשעים אחוז מערך העבודה, שכן מעשר היה צריך ממילא לשלם על אותה עבודה.

So the answer is that if the work that is done is something that can be billed (like an electrician working on a poor person's house), you can use it as part or all of you 10%, since your work has monetary value. He states that in this case, you should use your discounted rate if you give discounts, and you can only consider 90% of that towards the 10% you owe, because had you have gotten paid for this work, you would have to give another 10% on top of that.

Comment: +1 Seems though the worker needs to be a professional in the field who normally gets paid for this type of work.

Comment: @user6591 I don't know about professional, but at least something where you could request or demand payment.

Comment: Well I think if a programmer goes to his grandmother or neighbor to attach her oven he probably can't pretend he would have charged her as a plumber.